# ResizeObserver and MutationOberserver not working on production build

Tags: angular, resize, production-environment, mutation-observers

In my application, I'm using *ResizeObserver* and *MutationObserver* to make changes to my breadcrumb component. I'm observing the outer breadcrumb container for the changes in size (via ResizeContainer), and the inner container for added/removed elements (via MutationObserver) so the breadcrumb can collapse or expand when needed. Here are some code segments from the directive I wrote that works and does what it's supposed to do without any problems with `ng serve`:

```js
...
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.estimatedBreadcrumbWidth = 0;
    this.registerResizeObserver();
    this.registerMutationObserver();
  }

  private registerResizeObserver() {
    // @ts-ignore
    this.resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
      this.resizeObserverTimeoutId = this.debounceObservations(
        this.resizeObserverTimeoutId,
        this.timeoutThreshold,
        () => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            this.breadcrumbParentContainerWidth = this.elRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
            this.emitShouldBeCollapsedEvent();
          })
        }
      )
    });
    this.resizeObserver.observe(this.elRef.nativeElement);
  }

  private registerMutationObserver() {
    this.mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(() => {
      this.mutationObserverTimeoutId = this.debounceObservations(
        this.mutationObserverTimeoutId,
        this.timeoutThreshold,
        () => {
          this.estimatedBreadcrumbWidth = this.calculateBreadcrumbWidth(this.nodeElements);
          this.emitShouldBeCollapsedEvent();
        }
      )
    });
    this.mutationObserver.observe(this.elRef.nativeElement, {
      attributes: true,
      childList: true,
      characterData: true
    });
  }

  private debounceObservations(timeoutId: number, timeoutThreshold: number, operation: () => void): number {
    if (timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
    return window.setTimeout(operation, timeoutThreshold);
  }

...
```

As far as I know *ResizeObserver* callback still runs outside of zone so I'm manually running it in the zone with *NgZone*.

I'm not doing any additional imports for *MutationObserver* and *ResizeObserver* or using any specific polyfills for them.

Additionally here is the output of my `ng version` in case it can be helpful:

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 12.20.2
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.2.15
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.13.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.13.10
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core               7.3.10
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.3.9
@angular/cdk                       7.3.7
@angular/cli                       7.3.9
@angular/flex-layout               7.0.0-beta.24
@angular/material                  7.3.7
@angular/material-moment-adapter   7.3.7
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   7.3.9
@schematics/angular                7.3.9
@schematics/update                 0.13.9
ng-packagr                         4.7.1
rxjs                               6.5.5
typescript                         3.2.4
webpack                            4.29.0
```

However, the collapsing/uncollapsing of the breadcrumb doesn't work if I build the project in production mode. I'm also not receiving any errors during the build or after I serve the application.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens and is there a way to solve the issue?

I would also be interested in any other alternatives for *ResizeObserver* and *MutationObserver* in my situation if there is any.